# fatal error: linux/mount.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, include

I'm running `make` command to build a source code downloaded from [here](https://criu.org/Installation) . while running `make` it always throws the same error :

```
In file included from criu/cgroup.c:29:0:
criu/include/linux/mount.h:8:10: fatal error: linux/mount.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/mount.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I've checked multiple times the file does exist in the source code which i'm trying to build. But i do not understand why the compiler could not find it? what is the solution to handle these types of error?

**EDIT**: this source code contains another mount.h file in `criu/include/linux/mount.h` directory, inside that file, they have used `#include <linux/mount.h>`

**EDIT2**: the `mount.h` files was not present in `/usr/include/linux/` directory so i copied the file from the host's one to VM. Now i've successfully build the package and installed the binary but still one question i would like to ask is why the `mount.h` was not present on the VM.

Comment: what's your kernel version?

Answer (score 0):

> i do not understand why the compiler could not find it?

Because it's not supposed to. One should use

```c
#include "linux/mount.h"
```

rather than

```c
#include <linux/mount.h>
```

to include files from the project.

Comment: Hi, so am i supposed to change their source code directly? and even if i change every `#include <mount.h>` that will not create problem further?

Comment: and now i wonder it is released as a full package to install, before releasing didn't they tested it and found the same error.

Comment: on my host hernel, `mount.h` is present in `/usr/include/linux/mount.h` directory but in my VM this file is not present in that directory.